# How to change Column Delimiter in MS VSTS for web performance test

Tags: csv, performance-testing

I am using Microsoft VSTS for Performance test a web application

I am adding a Data Pool (.csv file) for parameterize multiple values, But the problem is .csv file is showing it in column delimited type like:

### VariableA,VariableB,Variable3

### Test1,Test2,Test3

## Test4,Test5,Test6

But i want these multiple values in single column, Because whenever we will select the column delimited type, .csv file automatically converts all values in different columns.
Like in HP-LoadRunner we have 3 options [Column, Tab, Space]. I tried to find out in VSTS data-pool settings but not able to find any option.
I am trying to do this:

### VariableA

### Test1,Test2,Test3

### Test5,Test6,Test7

Kindly help me out.

Comment: What is your question? Are you saying that you want `VariableA` to contain the value `Test1,Test2,Test3` on the first iteration and `Test5,Test6,Test7` on the second?

Comment: Yes AdrianHHH, VariableA to contain the value Test1,Test2,Test3 on the first iteration and Test5,Test6,Test7 on the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Test1,Test2,Test3 in first iteration, Test5,Test6,Test7 in second iteration then try below in your csv file.

VariableA

"Test1,Test2,Test3"

"Test5,Test6,Test7"

This should consider Test1,Test2,Test3 as a single variable.